# How to draw a guitar string using css?

Tags: css

Here is my attempt

```
.string{
    background: #b38f72; /* Old browsers */
    /* IE9 SVG, needs conditional override of 'filter' to 'none' */
    background: url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,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);
    background: -moz-repeating-linear-gradient(-45deg,  #b38f72 0%, #d0b27e 0.5%, #d3b888 1%, #8e6547 1.5%, #402116 2%, #3f2824 2.5%); /* FF3.6+ */
    background: -webkit-repeating-gradient(linear, left top, right top, color-stop(0%,#b38f72), color-stop(20%,#d0b27e), color-stop(40%,#d3b888), color-stop(60%,#8e6547), color-stop(80%,#402116), color-stop(100%,#3f2824)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
    background: -webkit-repeating-linear-gradient(left,  #b38f72 0%,#d0b27e 20%,#d3b888 40%,#8e6547 60%,#402116 80%,#3f2824 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
    background: -o-repeating-linear-gradient(left,  #b38f72 0%,#d0b27e 20%,#d3b888 40%,#8e6547 60%,#402116 80%,#3f2824 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
    background: -ms-repeating-linear-gradient(left,  #b38f72 0%,#d0b27e 20%,#d3b888 40%,#8e6547 60%,#402116 80%,#3f2824 100%); /* IE10+ */
    background: repeating-linear-gradient(to right,  #b38f72 0%,#d0b27e 20%,#d3b888 40%,#8e6547 60%,#402116 80%,#3f2824 100%); /* W3C */
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#b38f72', endColorstr='#3f2824',GradientType=1 ); /* IE6-8 */
    height:6px;
    width:100%;
    margin-top:20px
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/HmPkJ/

This is the kind of effect that I'm after.

https://forrst-live.s3.amazonaws.com/posts/snaps/94811/mega.jpg?1310500628

Any help would be appreciated...

Comment: Not really all that close, but maybe a step in the right direction - making the height: 0; and adding a dotted border: http://jsfiddle.net/HmPkJ/2/

Comment: Why not taking a small portion of string directly from that graphic that you provide and then applying it as a repeating background?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need 2 gradients, one repeating in horizontal, and another one with semitransparent parts in vertical

```
.test {
    position: absolute;
    height: 40px;
    width: 100%;

    background-image: 
          linear-gradient(0deg, black 0%, rgba(100, 100, 100, 0.2) 10% , white 50% , rgba(100, 100, 100, 0.2) 90% , gray 100% ), 
          repeating-linear-gradient(to right, black 0px, white 15px) 
    ;
}
```

### [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HmPkJ/3/)

Comment: I doesn't look close to me in chrome or firefox, but I think you are on the right lines with 2 gradients

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use an 5x5 image and just repeat the pattern ?

Comment: I need it to scale automatically for difference screen resolutions, so I assume gradients will work best

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
background-image: url('data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODdhAgAIAOMQAB0aFSUfDyooKTUxJkA6Gk9EJFlPLFRRSGtnZnNpUHRvXIF3bY+Ifp6Xh7Gunby4rywAAAAAAgAIAAAEDHAERV5xpiW20BFABAA7');
height: 8px;
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/TnWgY/)

Comment: Isn't that just an image rather than a gradient?

Comment: Not particularly well when scaled up and down